# TCPDF Page number as int

Tags: php, tcpdf

`$pdf->getAliasNumPage()` gets the page number in the content as string, which not works. Since I am tryting to determine what page number is next. So theoreticaly `$pdf->getAliasNumPage() + 1`;

I tryed using the `$pdf->PageNo();`, how ever it always returns 1. If I add it to footer as 
`$this` and `PageNo()` it works fine, but in the content. It doesn't.

Im using `$content .= lines;`

and

```
$pdf->writeHTML($content, true, 0, true, 0);
```

for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/), `getAliasNumPage()` is nothing more than placeholder text which eventually tells the TCPDF compiler to display the current page number. You can only use this function to display the current page number in your PDF and it cannot be used for logic such as the addition which you are trying to do.

Try it:

```
echo $pdf->getAliasNumPage();
die();
```

---

As for `PageNo()` the documentation does say that it returns an integer, **HOWEVER** this integer is only updated when you are not creating a PDF using `writeHTML()`. This integer only gets incremented after you call the `AddPage()` method yourself.

The reason for this is that when you are building your HTML, `PageNo()` is executed right away and is always on page #1. The `writeHTML()` function has no idea that you are trying to use `PageNo()` as an expression because the integer already exists in `$content`.

Since `$content` will render as a variable height block of content, TCPDF simply keeps overflowing it onto new pages as needed and the integer produced by `PageNo()` will always be the same.

In order for TCPDF to work the way you are trying to use it, TCPDF would have to provide an expression placeholder which the compiler would be able to understand and evaluate.

---

As for the footer, `PageNo()` works because the footer function is called on an as-needed basis.

From the docs:

> Footer( )
>
> This method is used to render the page footer. **It is automatically called by AddPage() and could be overwritten in your own inherited class.**

The bolded section explains why `PageNo()` actually gets incremented as expected in the footer. This holds true for the `Header()` as well.

Comment: @JeyTom I understand but given how TCPDF works, you are **NOT** able to dynamically change `$content` based on the page number. You can change contents of the header or footer, though. If you want to change body content based on the page number then you will need to learn how to use TCPDF without HTML code.

Comment: Allright, understood, thanks alot, do you think there is any other way to determine a count? to a $var? since the die() method just kills my script anyways. So its not really ideal. I m using it so if the same table keeps going to the next page, add some more rows with names on the top, so when somoene prints it, it would be easyer to read.

Comment: @JeyTom Why are you calling `die();`?? My example was just a proof of concept to TCPDF's internal behavior so it shouldn't be in your code. I think you should read my answer a few times fully because you still seem to think you can use an expression with `PageNo()` in the body of your PDF. Short answer, it is not possible.

Comment: it was just to point out, yeh I got that part, allright, I saw some people using page height to determine if the height is out of 1 page reach, I will try that method. Thanks alot anyways. I got my answer. :)

Comment: @JeyTom If you want "rows with names at the top" then you need to work them into your header instead of the body.

Comment: No its not that simple, ther eis more than 1 table minimum 5, they are generated from PHP part depending from what user chose to print out, and each table has different headings, each table is different height aswell, since it contains different amount of rows. So I need to manually check if table still goes on next page, if it does, at same headings for rows. So when user prints it out, he still knows what he is reading instead of fliping a paper back on forward.

Comment: @JeyTom It's never simple with PDF creation. Anyways, you could set up a global flag such as `$table_name = 'whatever';` and within the header function use `if( $GLOBALS[ 'table_name' ] === 'whatever' ){ /* do this header*/ }elseif( ...`. During your `$content` building process, just re-assign `$table_name` as needed and the header function will always pick up on it as-needed.

Comment: @JeyTom Working with heights is an absolute pain in the a$$.

Comment: Yeh thats why I tryed the page numbering first, instead of height. The global flag might actually work, tho Im getting a little bit scared for the generation time, if Ill add more loops to check the names than needed, it might be a bit too long, eh, worst case scenario, people will just need to flip the paper. Not to bad, just a little bit unconfy. Thanks a lot for help. Going to try the global first, then the height calc.

Comment: @JeyTom Your situation almost identically mirrors a project I did almost 4 years ago. Trust me, I do feel your pain. I don't think that it is terribly unreasonable for a new table to start on a new page unless the common output is one row per table for some reason. In any case, that's your battle. Good luck :)

Comment: @JeyTom Additionally, the global flag switching should not add anything noticeable to the PDF generation time; 2ms, if at all? This does assume that you're not performing some intense code within that `if()` sequence.

Comment: Yeh you are right, I will see where my luck leads me haha. Thanks for the tips, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Means this is not possible to check total page number in header part?
https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/bugs/1142/